# Splitting multiple pipe delimited values in multiple columns of a comma delimited CSV and mapping them to each other

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv with comma delimiters that has multiple values in a column that are delimited by a pipe and I need to map them to another column with multiple pipe delimited values and then give them their own row along with data in the original row that doesn't have multiple values. My CSV looks like this (with commas between the categories):

```
row    name                  city                          amount
1      frank | john | dave   toronto | new york | anaheim  10
2      george | joe | fred   fresno | kansas city | reno   20
```

I need it to look like this:

```
row    name    city          amount
1      frank   toronto       10
2      john    new york      10
3      dave    anaheim       10
4      george  fresno        20
5      joe     kansas city   20
6      fred    reno          20
```

Comment: Is all the data like your example?  Or are there some records that only have 1 name and 1 city.  IE    1, bob, Pittsburgh, 10

You can use .split('|') on the string and then reference each as a list  like   a_str.split('|')[0]

Comment: Yeah they should be consistent but some may have null values. EDIT: actually some only have one record per your example while others have three or four.

Comment: @KGBeans: it's best practice to show your input data file exactly as it is, without trying to pretty it up.  Otherwise, in order to test that an answer works, people have to insert commas manually instead of just copying and pasting.

Comment: Dear [@KGBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5651345/kgbeans), Was my answer (or the other answer) helpful for you? If yes, would you please vote it and mark as an answer? If not would you specify why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the nicest but working solution:
(works with no piped lines and for different pipe-length)

```
df = pd.read_csv('<your_data>.csv')
str_split = ' | '

# Calculate maximum length of piped (' | ') values
df['max_len'] = df[['name', 'city']].apply(lambda x: max(len(x[0].split(str_split)),
    len(x[0].split(str_split))), axis=1)
max_len = df['max_len'].max()

# Split '|' piped cell values into columns (needed at unpivot step)
# Create as many new 'name_<x>' & 'city_<x>' columns as 'max_len'
df[['name_{}'.format(i) for i in range(max_len)]] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: \
    pd.Series(x.split(str_split)))
df[['city_{}'.format(i) for i in range(max_len)]] = df['city'].apply(lambda x: \
    pd.Series(x.split(str_split)))

# Unpivot 'name_<x>' & 'city_<x>' columns into rows
df_pv_name = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['name_{}'.format(i) for i in range(max_len)],
    id_vars=['amount'])
df_pv_city = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['city_{}'.format(i) for i in range(max_len)],
    id_vars=['amount'])

# Rename upivoted columns (these are the final columns)
df_pv_name = df_pv_name.rename(columns={'value':'name'})
df_pv_city = df_pv_city.rename(columns={'value':'city'})

# Rename 'city_<x>' values (rows) to be 'key' for join (merge)
df_pv_city['variable'] = df_pv_city['variable'].map({'city_{}'.format(i):'name_{}'\
    .format(i) for i in range(max_len)})

# Join unpivoted 'name' & 'city' dataframes
df_res = df_pv_name.merge(df_pv_city, on=['variable', 'amount'])

# Drop 'variable' column and NULL rows if you have not equal pipe-length in original rows
# If you want to drop any NULL rows then replace 'all' to 'any'
df_res = df_res.drop(['variable'], axis=1).dropna(subset=['name', 'city'], how='all',
    axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
   amount    name         city
0      10   frank      toronto
1      20  george       fresno
2      10    john     new york
3      20     joe  kansas city
4      10    dave      anaheim
5      20    fred         reno
```

Another test input:

```
                               name                                                  city  amount
0  frank | john | dave | joe | bill  toronto | new york | anaheim | los angeles | caracas      10
1               george | joe | fred                                  fresno | kansas city      20
2                             danny                                                 miami      30
```

Result of this test (if you don't want `NaN` rows then replace `how='all'` to `how='any'` in the code at merging):

```
   amount    name         city
0      10   frank      toronto
1      20  george       fresno
2      30   danny        miami
3      10    john     new york
4      20     joe  kansas city
5      10    dave      anaheim
6      20    fred          NaN
7      10     joe  los angeles
8      10    bill      caracas
```

Comment: What is "df['max_len'] = df[['name', 'city']].apply(lambda x: max(len(x[0].split(str_split)),
    len(x[0].split(str_split))), axis=1)
max_len = df['max_len'].max()" doing?

Comment: I updated the code with comments. I hope you can use it. In this problem we need some kind of pivot (unpivot = `pd.melt()`), and doing this we need columns with separate values instead of piped values.

Answer (score 1):

Given a row:

```
['1','frank|joe|dave', 'toronto|new york|anaheim', '20']
```

you can use

```
itertools.izip_longest(*[value.split('|') for value in row])
```

on it to obtain following structure:

```
[('1', 'frank', 'toronto', '20'),
 (None, 'joe', 'new york', None),
 (None, 'dave', 'anaheim', None)]
```

Here we want to replace all `None` values with last seen value in corresponding column. Can be done when looping over result.

So given a TSV already splitted by tabs following code should do the trick:

```
import itertools 


def flatten_tsv(lines):
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        flat_lines = itertools.izip_longest(*[value.split('|') for value in line])
        for flat_line in flat_lines:
            result.append([result[-1][i] if v is None else v 
                           for i, v in enumerate(flat_line)])
    return result
```